# Set jQuery Modal Cookie to Expire in 7 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, onload

I need to make my jquery modal on the home page only that appears on page load to re-appear (onload) after 7 days.  Here is my current code and I'm confused on the date duration. I can;t figure out what to change.

Here is my current code:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1){
   
$('#ex1').modal({show:true});
var year = 1000*60*60*24*7;
var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + year);
document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
 }
});
```

Comment: Using the browser's console, the expires calculation shows: `Date Fri Sep 10 2021 23:08:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`, and the `toUTCSting()` shows: `"Sat, 11 Sep 2021 03:08:21 GMT"`

Comment: Is there an easier way to set 7 days ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function, it can be reusable and easy to read

```
function setCookie(variable, value, expires_days) { 
    let d = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * expires_days);
    document.cookie = variable + '=' + value + '; expires=' + d.toGMTString() + ';';
}
setCookie("visited", "true", 7);
```